# How to comment on the Solution via Convex relaxation?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, convex-optimization, matrix-rank

I have an optimization program that searches for $\mathbf{X}$ that minimizes some objective function. My setup is as follows

1. Objective function being convex
2. A linear constrain $\mathbf{Xy=b}$
3. A rank-1 constrain $rank(\mathbf{X})=1$

Solving this program will return me a solution that might just be a local minimum. I will call this solution $\tilde{\mathbf{X}}$.

Since rank-1 constrain makes it a non-convex problem, I keep only linear constrain. It turns out that solving new problem with convex objective function and a linear constrain gives me a solution $\mathbf{X^*}$ which has $\sigma_i<<\sigma_1\quad \forall \quad i>2$ ($\sigma$'s comes from $svd(\mathbf{X^*})$). Therefore, it turns out that $\mathbf{X^*}$ is *effectively* **rank-1**.

How should I argue that the two solutions $\tilde{\mathbf{X}}$ and $\mathbf{X^*}$ are nearby matrices. And we dont loose much by doing this convex relaxation?

**One option for me is to show that**

\begin{equation}
\|\mathbf{X^*}-\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\|_1\leq\epsilon
\end{equation}

Any other idea will be much appreciated

Comment: If the solution to the convex problem is rank 1, then it _is_ the solution to your original problem. Because adding the rank-1 constraint only _restricts_ the solution space.

Comment: It is not exactly rank-1, but only one singular value is dominant. rest are very small. I want to say, in a principled way, that this local minima $\tilde{\mathbf{X}}$ is **close** to optimal $\mathbf{X^*}$

Comment: But no numerical method is going to give you an exact result. So the question is: are the singular values of $X^*$ such that it is rank 1 _to within the solver's numerical precision_?

Comment: Right.....i had not thought of bringing in the question of numerical precision into the equation. Thank you for your comment.